# Can I access ReimburseCharge objects in the IPP QBO v3 API?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I queried an Invoice that contains a billable expense charge. The response includes (and I'm showing just the relevant portions of it):

```
....
"Line": [
    {
        "LineNum": 1, 
        "DescriptionLineDetail": {
            "ServiceDate": "2015-11-15"
        }, 
        "Id": "3", 
        "DetailType": "DescriptionOnly", 
        "Description": "Test Billable Transaction 1"
    }, 
    {
        "LineNum": 2, 
        "DescriptionLineDetail": {
            "ServiceDate": "2015-11-15"
        }, 
        "Id": "4", 
        "DetailType": "DescriptionOnly", 
        "Description": "Test Billable Expense Transaction 3"
    }, 
    {
        "DetailType": "SubTotalLineDetail", 
        "Amount": 8.01, 
        "SubTotalLineDetail": {}
    }
], 
"LinkedTxn": [
    {
        "TxnId": "1938", 
        "TxnType": "ReimburseCharge"
    }, 
    {
        "TxnId": "1932", 
        "TxnType": "ReimburseCharge"
    }
],
...
```

I tried querying the API for ReimburseCharge and got only errors back. Is this business object on the roadmap?

On a related note, I observe that a billable line (at least in Purchase objects) can have its BillableStatus attribute set to "HasBeenBilled" with an Update call. It cannot be set *back* to "Billable" without *first* setting it to "NotBillable", but this does seem to work more than once so that it's not a one-way effect. If the line has *actually* been billed though, I get a validation fault when I try to change the BillableStatus from "HasBeenBilled" to "NotBillable", which I suppose makes sense.

**Here's what's decidedly problematic though: I cannot use the API to either link a billable expense to an invoice or figure out where an already-linked expense is invoiced. Also, I cannot see the amount of the individual lines contained in these "DescriptionOnly" lines, so all I get is the total. Does Intuit have plans to change this and, if so, when?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This decision for supporting Reimb Charge is still pending.
Regarding DescriptionOnly- This was meant to support only total and sub totals.
So, if you have to use lines then you should use SalesItemLineDetail

Comment: have there been any updates on this?  I'm having the same problem about a year later.  Need to total time and expense items for an invoice, and, while there is a ReimburseCharge item in linked transactions for an invoice, it doesn't match any actual Purchase entities.  When I add a new one, I end up with an id in the linked transaction for the invoice that doesn't match the actual id of the new Purchase entity, which I can pull by amount, but have no way to link to the invoice it was billed on.

Comment: This is still not supported and might not be supported for next 6months alteast.

Comment: Hi, Thanks.  Are there any workarounds?  Linking invoices with the things that are billed on them is sort of square one when it comes to accounting software...

Comment: Only delayed charge and reimbursable charge entities cannot be queried. There is no workaround.

Comment: Rest all linked txn entities can be queried,- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0200_dev_guides/accounting/linked_transactions